# How can I use an error as an if statement in R

Tags: r

I'm using the function "trycatch" to skip some errors in a loop in R and I would like to use the error message in an if statement, but I don't know how to do that. I would like to increment a counter only under the condition that there is no error, because "trycatch" skip the error correctly, but also increments the counter. This is my code if you want to see it:

```
n=1000

j=0
true.out<-matrix(0,nrow=1000,ncol=500)
ident.out<-matrix(0,nrow=1000,ncol=500)

for(i in 1:n )
{tryCatch({
 serie<-gen_3_out_garch(500,0.0126,0.0757,0.9122,3,i,i,info=F,plot=T)
 info<-gen_3_out_garch(500,0.0126,0.0757,0.9122,3,i,i,info=T,plot=F)
 A<-Ric_Doornik_Ooms(serie)

out_presenti<-info$"caratteristiche outliers"[,1]
out_rilevati<-as.numeric(A[,1])
true.out[j,out_presenti]<-1
ident.out[j,out_rilevati]<-2

}, error=function(e){print(paste("error in rugarch"))
                    })
}
```

But the only think I need to know is how to write something like:

```
 if("there are no errors")
 {j=j+1)
```

thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

try

```
loadError=F
a=try({...})
loadError <- (is(a, 'try-error')|is(a,'error'))
if(loadError==F){
  j=j+1
}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, I have to use the "try" function and not "trycatch"? Then, my loop is inside the trycatch function, how can I put the condition inside? Thanks

Comment: @RiccardoRedaelli if i right understand what you want , try `for(i in 1:n )
{loadError=F
  a=try({
  serie<-gen_3_out_garch(500,0.0126,0.0757,0.9122,3,i,i,info=F,plot=T)
  info<-gen_3_out_garch(500,0.0126,0.0757,0.9122,3,i,i,info=T,plot=F)
  A<-Ric_Doornik_Ooms(serie)
  
  out_presenti<-info$"caratteristiche outliers"[,1]
  out_rilevati<-as.numeric(A[,1])
  true.out[j,out_presenti]<-1
  ident.out[j,out_rilevati]<-2
  
})
loadError <- (is(a, 'try-error')|is(a,'error'))
if(loadError==F){
  j=j+1
}
}`

Comment: perfect, it works even if I put  A <- Ric_Doornik_Ooms(serie) inside (is(a, 'try-error')|is(a,'error')), infact the error occurred in that function. Thank you very much!!! I was there for the whole afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return FALSE on error and test against the return value from your `tryCatch`

```
for(i in 1:n ) {
    test <- tryCatch({
        serie <- gen_3_out_garch(500,0.0126,0.0757,0.9122,3,i,i,info=F,plot=T)
        info <- gen_3_out_garch(500,0.0126,0.0757,0.9122,3,i,i,info=T,plot=F)
        A <- Ric_Doornik_Ooms(serie)

        out_presenti <- info$"caratteristiche outliers"[,1]
        out_rilevati <- as.numeric(A[,1])
        true.out[j,out_presenti] <- 1
        ident.out[j,out_rilevati] <- 2
        TRUE
    }, error=function(e){
        print(paste("error in rugarch"))
        FALSE
    })
    if (!test) j <- j+1
}
```

or you could increment j from the error function

```
tryCatch({
   ...
}, error=function(e) j <<- j+1 )
```

Comment: Another way to do that, perfect. Thank you very much,

Comment: The best way to thank @Rorschach is to upvote his answer and, if you feel so, accept it.